# Cant get passed a malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

Hello im trying to create a heap in c! This is my struct for the heap.

```
struct heap{
   double* array;
   int maxSize;
   int currentSize;
};
```

This is my main:

```
int n;
double  *array1,hmax;
struct heap *h;
int i;

printf("\n Enter the number of elements: ");
scanf(" %d",&n);
array1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
printf("\n Forming the heap please wait...\n");
for( i=1;i<=n;i++ ){
     array1[i]=(double)rand()/1000;
     printf("%.2f /",array1[i]);
}

printf("\n Now the array in heap form is: ");
 for( i=1;i<=n;i++ ){
      printf("\n %.2f",array1[i]);
 }
h=createHeap(array1,n);
```

And the createHeap method is this:

```
struct heap* createHeap( double array1[],int length ){

 int i;

 struct heap *h=(struct heap*)malloc(sizeof(struct heap*));
 if( !h ){
     printf("No free memory system exit...\n");
     abort();
 }

 h->maxSize=length;
 h->currentSize=0;

 h->array=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(h->maxSize+1));
  printf("here");
 if( !h->array ){  
     fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!\n");
     abort();
 }

 for( i=0; i<length; i++ ){
      h->array[i+1]=array1[i];
 }
 h->currentSize=length;

 for( i=h->maxSize/2; i>0; i-- ){
      heapify(h,i);
 }

 return h;
```

In this method im creating and inserting all the double numbers in the heap. I cant though get passed the array malloc. I tried everything and still i cannot make it work!
Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you all.

Comment: You are allocating size of a pointer -- `malloc(sizeof(struct heap*))` where you need to allocate `sizeof(struct heap)`.

Comment: yes but its the only way to get passed there. i cant allocate with malloc(sizeof(struct heap)) it crashes and i cand find out why!!

Comment: Is that what the `printf("here")` is for? Add `fflush(stdout)` after such lines, as it may help you. Or use a debugger. BTW your array copying loop is also wrong, it fills the array with copies of the first element. (Unless that was your intention, of course.)

Comment: yes the pprintf("here"); is there as a "debug" tool. Also i wnat to fill the array in the heap with the elements of the array1, so i think   it is right. So no thoughts why i cant get passed he malloc?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies elsewhere. (Although the aforementioned `malloc` is *also* a problem.)

You are not initializing your initial struct `array` correctly in the `main` routine:

```
array1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
printf("\n Forming the heap please wait...\n");
for( i=1;i<=n;i++ ){
     array1[i]=(double)rand()/1000;
     printf("%.2f /",array1[i]);
}
```

This writes data into `array1[1]` to `array1[n]`, but that last value is not valid in C. An array of length *n* starts at `0` and ends at `n-1`. Change the loop to

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Most likely, what happens is that random memory gets overwritten, and thus you get an unrelated error 'somewhere else'.

Comment: Wow it really worked thank you so much!! What a silly mistake there! I was working this programm for 3 hours and still didnt find anything!! Thank  you!!

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong.

```
struct heap *h=(struct heap*)malloc(sizeof(struct heap*));
```

It needs to be:

```
struct heap *h=malloc(sizeof(struct heap));
```

Comment: again it cant get passed struct heap *h=malloc(sizeof(struct heap)); line. it is crushing!

Comment: If it is crashing, you **must** describe the crash.  Is it a seg-fault?  What line does it refer to?  What *exactly* is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

These lines together do not make sense:

```
array1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++ ){
```

You allocate an array with n elements, but then try to write all the way to the end of the array, and 1 element after the end!

Instead, your for-loop should look like:

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ ){
```

**Remember**:
In C, arrays are ZERO-based, not 1-based.
The first element is `array1[0]`.  The last element is `array1[n-1]`.
And element `array1[n]` is **INVALID**.